# How to solve animation issue of Text with other animations?

Tags: macos, swiftui

This is my code for macOS that I have animation issue for Text:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var text: String = "Hello"
    @State private var height: CGFloat = 300.0

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text(text)
                .bold()
                .fixedSize()
                .onTapGesture {
                    height += 50.0
                    text = text + " updated "
                }
                .animation(.default, value: text)
            
        }
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .frame(width: 400.0, height: height)
        .animation(.default, value: height)
    }
}
```

My goal is to animate text change in Text, also having height change animation, I am not looking to animate window itself, but the VStack, currently animation of Text blocks the height animation, and the result is sudden jump in content, how to solve the issue for having both animations running.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify how you expect the text to animate. Are you expecting it to grow, letter by letter? This will only happen if you append the letters one by one, which you're not doing. Also, it might help if you remove the ```fixedSize```, otherwise the text always stays on one line and overflows the screen bounds, instead of wrapping.

Comment: I am ok with any animation I got from apple API for Text, the issue is jumping content without any animation. PS: I am also fine with overflows of Text.

Comment: I have been trying your example code in an iPhone 14 Pro simulator running iOS 16.4 (Xcode 14.3.1) and it doesn't jump. What did you use to record the animated gif and what is the line at the bottom that seems to be moving down? Looks like you're running different code.

Comment: As I tagged in begging it is macOS.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that, sorry.